# IncludeItemInSelection not working with CustomListItem with InputField in OpenUI5 > 1.28

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

Currently I am migrating a project from 1.26 to > 1.28.

Something changed in the behavior, of InputFields in CustomListItems in a list with SingleSelect and the property includeItemInSelection applied to it.

Prior to 1.28 the behavior was:

```
var oTable = new sap.m.Table({
    mode: sap.m.ListMode.SingleSelectLeft,
    includeItemInSelection: true,
    columns: [
      new sap.m.Column({ header: new sap.m.Label({text: "Value"})})
    ],
    items: {
      path: "/",
      template: new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells: [
          new sap.m.Input({ value: "{value}" })
        ]
      })
    },
  });
```

When the Input Field got the focus, the CustomListItem was also selected, when the property includeItemInSelection was set for the table.

You can see that behavior in that jsbin:
**[JSBin Example 1.26](http://jsbin.com/noruqabiju/1/edit?html,output)**

When I switch the openui5 version to 1.28 and greater the custom list item is not autoselected anymore, when I click into the input field:
**[JSBin Example 1.28](http://jsbin.com/tehigifogu/edit?html,output)**

**UPDATE**:
When I run the JSBins in debug mode, the following log output is produced, when I click into one of the input fields:

Here is a nicer diff view:
https://www.diffnow.com/?report=ywku5

Comment: Sounds like a behavior change ^^ the 1.28 patch note (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#releasenotes.html) contains lots of references to 'focus' but I find it hard to tell if one of the fix is involved here (du to minimal fix description in patch note). It looks like a regression though since what you are expecting seemsto be the normal behavior